# How to vertically center multiple rows in an AppBar in Material-UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm attempting to vertically center multiple items/rows in a Material-UI AppBar/ToolBar but it doesn't seem to work

This is what I have...

[image]

And this is what I would like...

[image]

This is my code...

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  appBar: {
    height: 200,
    width: `calc(100% - 200px)`,
    marginLeft: 200
  },
  link: {
    display: "flex",
    color: "white"
  },
  icon: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(0.5),
    width: 20,
    height: 20
  },
  toolbar: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignItems: "flex-start",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  drawerPaper: {
    display: "flex",
    width: 200
  }
}));

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AppBar position="fixed" className={classes.appBar}>
        <Toolbar className={classes.toolbar}>
          <Typography variant="h6" noWrap>
            Payments
          </Typography>
          <Breadcrumbs aria-label="breadcrumb">
            <Link href="/" className={classes.link}>
              <HomeIcon className={classes.icon} />
              Home
            </Link>
            <Link
              href="/getting-started/installation/"
              className={classes.link}
            >
              <HomeIcon className={classes.icon} />
              Reports
            </Link>
          </Breadcrumbs>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      // Other stuff
```

I thought this bit would do it but apparently not

```
toolbar: {
  display: "flex",
  flexDirection: "column",
  alignItems: "flex-start",
  justifyContent: "center"
},
```

Code sandbox is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-silence-5rve2)

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think adding flex in appBar with flexDirection column and then making it center, will work

```
 appBar: {
    height: 200,
    width: `calc(100% - 200px)`,
    marginLeft: 200,
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm guessing `justifyContent: "center"` in the toolbar doesn't really work unless the appbar is centered first.

Comment: Yes, to make the child(Toolbar) center, apply justifyContent: "center" in the parent(AppBar). You can refer to https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

In your toolbar class add this,

> alignItems: "flex-start",
> justifyContent: "center",
> height: "100%"